# Liferay Group types

Tags: types, liferay

When I run the following sql

```
select distinct(type_) from Group_
```

I get group types 0,1,3 in my database table `Group_`.

What does 0 , 1 and 3 mean, and are there any other possible values?

Comment: Got the Answer from com.liferay.portal.model.GroupConstants 

TYPE_COMMUNITY_OPEN = 1
TYPE_COMMUNITY_RESTRICTED = 2
TYPE_COMMUNITY_PRIVATE = 3
DEFAULT_PARENT_GROUP_ID = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the Answer from `com.liferay.portal.model.GroupConstants`

```
TYPE_COMMUNITY_OPEN = 1,
TYPE_COMMUNITY_RESTRICTED = 2,
TYPE_COMMUNITY_PRIVATE = 3,
DEFAULT_PARENT_GROUP_ID = 0
```